# c# MVC 5 - Get current value from Layout in Application_Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have many different layouts in my app and if it's an error on a page I want to use the same layout as the page where the error occurred.

Is it possible to get the value from the Layout in the Application_Error method so I can set this Layout when I return my Error view?

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Logic to gather error and redirect to error controller
}
```

Comment: Can't see anything here about how you get the Layout value

Comment: You probably have to keep the layout in the TempData collection so you can access it again. You would have to either write an Html helper extension to do this (very minimal code required) or add it to the top of each cshtml page. Then you could access it from the error view.

Comment: Hmm yea that kind of works. How would you write a html helper for that so I dont have to write that on each cshtml page?